# XSL Repeating Same XML Element/Node, Not Working Correctly

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, stylesheet

So this is what my XML looks like. It's pretty darn simple, just want to lay out a bunch of links to other XML files with different names/titles for each link of course:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<playToc>
    <play>a_and_c.xml</play>
    <play>all_well.xml</play>
    <play>as_you.xml</play>
    <play>com_err.xml</play>
    <play>coriolan.xml</play>
    <play>cymbelin.xml</play>
    <name>Title 1</name>
    <name>Title 2</name>
    <name>Title 3</name>
    <name>Title 4</name>
    <name>Title 5</name>
    <name>Title 6</name>
</playToc>
```

Pretty simple, right? And so here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="playToc">
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<xsl:apply-templates select="play"></xsl:apply-templates>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="play">

<xsl:variable name="URL">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="TITLE">
    <xsl:value-of select="../name"/> 
</xsl:variable>

<a href="{$URL}"><xsl:value-of select="$TITLE"/></a>
<br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the output:

```
Title 1
Title 1
Title 1
Title 1
Title 1
Title 1
```

When I want this to be the output, of course:

```
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
Title 5
Title 6
```

Any help would be so great! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="TITLE">      
>  <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>   
> </xsl:variable>
> ```

Your problem is here.

The string value of `../name` is the string value of *the first* `name` child of the parent of the initial context (current) node.

What you actually want is to get the value of the `name` child that has the same position as the position of the current (`play`) node.

**This complete and short transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="play">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
     <a href="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="../name[$vPos]"/>
     </a><br />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<playToc>
    <play>a_and_c.xml</play>
    <play>all_well.xml</play>
    <play>as_you.xml</play>
    <play>com_err.xml</play>
    <play>coriolan.xml</play>
    <play>cymbelin.xml</play>
    <name>Title 1</name>
    <name>Title 2</name>
    <name>Title 3</name>
    <name>Title 4</name>
    <name>Title 5</name>
    <name>Title 6</name>
</playToc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<a href="a_and_c.xml">Title 1</a>
<br/>
<a href="all_well.xml">Title 2</a>
<br/>
<a href="as_you.xml">Title 3</a>
<br/>
<a href="com_err.xml">Title 4</a>
<br/>
<a href="coriolan.xml">Title 5</a>
<br/>
<a href="cymbelin.xml">Title 6</a>
<br/>
```

**Do note**:

1. There is *no* need to use `xsl:apply-templates` at all.
2. There is just one template.

Comment: This is just a snippet of my XML, so I do have to use apply-templates for a bunch of my overall XML.

Comment: @Encephalon, Of course, you need to adapt this solution to your real code -- hope this is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Well the XML input is poorly structured but you can work around this by doing

```
<xsl:template match="play">
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
  <a href="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="../name[position() = $pos]"/>
  </a>
  <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Make sure you keep the `<xsl:apply-templates select="play"/>` in the other template, otherwise the approach with `position()` won't work.

Comment: Martin Honnen, There is *no* need to use `xsl:apply-templates` at all.